# Do trees continue growing once they have sprouted?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

After a sapling has sprouted into a tree, will the tree still continue growing and expanding?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, they will not. After a sapling instantaneously grows into a tree, it will never get any bigger than it is.

Comment: Trees stop growing the moment it's no longer a **sapling**. Trees won't grow from 1 wood block.