# Can I add wood to trees to make them bigger?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In minecraft, can I put wood blocks on top of trees to make them grow larger?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do trees continue growing once they have sprouted?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29671/do-trees-continue-growing-once-they-have-sprouted)

Comment: VTLO; the answers are the same, but the questions are not necessarily so.

Answer (score 18):

No, but technically you can plant a [tree](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tree) using a dirt block on top of/inside another tree to grow another tree. This sort of expands the tree, but the second tree will grow normally (and requires the same conditions as a normal tree to grow), but with a little bit of work you can grow huge "trees" and prune them to your liking this way. The top tree will still grow leaves, but it might be a small tree and thus not as impressive. You can always replace/regrow a tree anywhere you want inside the 'base' tree though.

Remember you can also use Shears on [Leaf Blocks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Leaves) ti collect them, and you can make your own tree manually with Leaf and Wood blocks, but they won't exhibit some of the properties of [properly grown trees](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tree) like natural branches.

Comment: Yeah, I did this. When I was done, the tree reached enormous heights and basically was like a labyrinth. :)

Comment: You can also use shears to collect leaf blocks and then build your own tree!

Comment: @SaintWacko added that info in. Do "natural" trees' branches/leaves actually grow back or not? I used to think they did, but I'm not sure

Comment: @BenBrocka No, they don't

Answer (score 9):

You put four jungle saplings in square, and use bonemeal on it to make a huge tree, with vines. (This only works in a jungle biome.)

There are also some tricks to grow small trees or big trees. If you dig a 1-block hole and plant a sapling in it will make a big tree. Dig a two-block hole and plant a sapling in it and it will make a small tree.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I wasn't able to create a 'HUUUGE' tree - only four regular ones.

Comment: Did you discover the jungle biomes ? Take some saplings from those big trees, plant four in square and use bonemeal on them. I don't know if it's about the saplings that are different or if you must do this IN the jungle biomes. Though it works, I already did that.

Comment: Aha, I wasn't in a jungle biome. And I should only have to use one bonemeal, right?

Comment: Yep that's right. One bonemeal on one of the four saplings and it should grow a 'HUUUGE' tree x)

Comment: You can do this not in a jungle biome. I have a huge jungle tree in a mushroom biome. However you can ONLY do it with jungle trees.

Answer (score 8):

Once a tree grows, it's done, so no, adding logs to a tree won't make it grow any larger.  In a similar vein, harvested logs or leaves also won't grow back, although the leaves can decay without nearby wood.

Answer (score 2):

you can not add in the way you are thinking, but if you have time, shears, and logs you can build your own "designer" tree. placing the logs and leaves just how you want them. if all you want is a massive tree, just put four jungle saplings in a 2x2 pattern.

Comment: This bug was fixed. You need 4 jungle saplings.